# Can "Visual Studio 2013 for Web" show mixins from referenced files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less

The answer is "Yes it can", but somehow it does not work correctly. I created project where I wrote some code. First I wrote it in one file, when it was too big I cut some code and paste it into separate files. Then I used only "@import" and everything including intelisense was working perfectly.

Then I started new project and copied and added to the project those files especially "mixins.less". I imported it like in last project but this time intelisense is not working at all. It compiles and runs correctly, just intelisense is not working.

So I started to dig in and found something like this:

[very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093328/can-visual-studio-2013-show-mixins-from-referenced-files)

> If I understand you correctly, you have imported less files and you would like to get intelliSense on things like mixins and variables when you hover over them.
>
> This can be done by referencing the files in the same way you would with JavaScript files.
>
> Example

`/// <reference path="mixins.less" />`

`@import "mixins.less";`

`.some-mixin;`

> You can now hover over the mixin and see what it does!
>
> answered Apr 18 at 14:09
>
> Colin Bacon

I tried it and it does not work. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is working. Weird thing but I deleted all the imports and left only:

```
/// <reference path="mixins.less" />

@import "mixins.less";
```

Then 1 second after I pasted rest of the imports and it is working now. :)